# Number Picker displays numbers out of margin

Tags: android, user-interface, numberpicker

I've been trying to fix this issue for hours now but it looks like I'm the only one having it.

[image: NumberPickers]

I shouldn't see the number above and below the blue line. Here is the XML

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:useDefaultMargins="true"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            app:columnCount="3"
            app:rowCount="7">

    ........

    <NumberPicker
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="3"
            android:id="@+id/n_of_dies"
            style="@style/inputNumbers"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            />
     <NumberPicker
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="4"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/carbon_content"
            style="@style/inputNumbers" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            />
      ........
```

The content of Input numbers is

```
 <style name="inputNumbers">
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
    </style>
```

any ideas?

Comment: You should put the content of your `@style/inputNumbers` too

Comment: And here is the issue. Basically the padding in the style spoil the component... I removed the padding and everything looks good now.

Answer (score 1):

Given the problem is how you're using the paddings I'd recommend to take a look at the widget style (the Holo variation) if you want to change the [default look](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml#L1689):

```
...

<style name="Widget.NumberPicker">
  <item name="android:internalLayout">@android:layout/number_picker</item>
  <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
  <item name="android:fadingEdge">vertical</item>
  <item name="android:fadingEdgeLength">50dip</item>
</style>

...

<style name="Widget.Holo.NumberPicker" parent="Widget.NumberPicker">
  <item name="android:internalLayout">@android:layout/number_picker_with_selector_wheel</item>
  <item name="android:solidColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
  <item name="android:selectionDivider">@android:drawable/numberpicker_selection_divider</item>
  <item name="android:selectionDividerHeight">2dip</item>
  <item name="android:selectionDividersDistance">48dip</item>
  <item name="android:internalMinWidth">64dip</item>
  <item name="android:internalMaxHeight">180dip</item>
  <item name="virtualButtonPressedDrawable">?android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
</style>
```